# numpy where: how to find a 2D array's index in a 3D array by matching a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3], (1,1,0,0,8)], [[1,2,3], (1,1,2,0,8)], [[1,2,3], (4,1,0,0,8)]])
where = np.where(a[:,1] == (1,1,0,0,8))
print(where)
```

outputs:

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I want it to output `0`, the index of the row where `(1,1,0,0,8)` appears

Comment: The problem is that numpy treats the tuple as an array-like input for elementwise comparison. Simpler example: `np.array([1,0,3]) == (1,2,3)` returns `array([True, False, True])`

Comment: `a` isn't 3d.  Its shape is (3,2).  In new enough numpy versions you'll get `VisibleDeprecationWarning`.  Dtype is `object`  When `where` doesn't give expected results, look at the the `cond` .  `where` only finds the `non-zero/True` elements of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy usually interprets a tuple as an array or subset of an array instead of an element, but you can get around it with this:

```
el = np.array([None], dtype = object)
el[0] = (1,1,0,0,8)

where = np.where( a[:,1] == el ) # outputs a tuple: (array([0], dtype=int64),)
```